# d3.js: force simulation starts slowly (but runs smooth)

Tags: typescript, svg, d3.js, d3-force

I'm trying to create a basic force simulation with 4 nodes and 3 links. Init logic looks like this:

```
d3.forceSimulation(this.data.nodes).on('end', ticked(this.data));

function ticked(data) {
    console.log('ticked 1');
    return function () {
        console.log('ticked 2');
        // click listeners for nodes are created below
    }
}
```

Now to the problem: the first log (`ticked 1`) comes up almost immediately, but not the second one (`ticked 2`) although it is the first line in the returned function?!
Is there an other way to properly add event listeners?